# how to store list in a database, without using many-to-many/one-to-many?

Tags: database, arrays, list, schema, relationship

here is what i am trying to do, i want to store a list of values within a db record, so it is something like this:

```
| id |  tags     |
| 1  |  1,3,5    |
| 2  |  121,4,6  |
| 3  |  3,101,2  |
```

most of the suggestion i found so far suggest creating a separate join table to establish a many-to-many relationship, but in my case, i dont think it is suitable to create a separate table because the tags values are just a list of numbers.

the best i can think of right now is to store the data as a csv string, and parse it accordingly when it is retrieved, but i'm still trying to find a way where i can get the values as an array when i retrieve it from the db, even better if i can restrict the number of elements in the list, is there any better way to do this?

I haven't decided which database to use yet, most probably postgresql, but im open to others if it can help me implement this better,

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Whenever I had to do something like you described (which I did from time to time), I felt bad for not using a child table. Then, I added them as a string of comma-separated values.

Comment: @dash1e, i havent decided which db to use yet, but most probably, i will be going with postgre

Comment: @Uwe Keim, that is what im going to do as well, if i cant find a better way, :)

Comment: Are 1,2,3,4 really id's from a 'tag' table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On PostgreSQL you can use [array type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html).

On MySQL you can use [set type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html).

Then it depends on what you really need.

Comment: awesome, didnt know that before, i guess i'll have to look more beyond ORMs... thanks!